# "二つ目のお話しのtheme" vs. "二つのお話しのtheme" nuance difference?

Tags: nuances, counters

> (1) **二つ目**のお話のthemeは愛と失意{しつい}です。
>   (2) **二つ**のお話のthemeは愛と失意です。

Fundamentally, both sentences mean

> The two themes of this talk are love and despair.

What is the difference in meaning / nuance between #1 and #2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one means

> The themes of the **second** talk are love and despair.

The second one means

> The themes of the two talks are love and despair　→　implying either 1) that one talk is about love, and the other is about despair, **or** 2) they are *both* about both love and despair.

Comment: yes. I see what happened. In one long speech, the person recounted two stories that each had a different themes. Within one presentation you can have multiple "話し".